# 2-month contract in a remote area with night shifts; any clinical studies I should be interested in if I'd like to cope?

Tags: clinical-psychology

I've recently taken a 2-month contract in a remote part of the country where I'll be doing night shifts for all of it. I've done night shift work in the past without much issue, but I've never been isolated for long periods of time, and I feel like this is a very real possibility since there's probably next to no nightlife where I'll be going. I don't know how much human contact I'll have, but very likely it will be minimal and mostly job related, but trying to make friends is obviously the first thing I'll try doing.

In the mean time, I've come to realize that this will probably be a straining or a difficult experience if I don't prepare accordingly, and I thought that maybe the best thing to do is to read up on psychology literature of similar situations. My main worry is that is it likely I'll have very little contact with people most weeks.

Since I don't really know where to look for advice on this sort of situation, and no one I know has been through something similar, I thought that the best place to start would be looking up clinical studies of people undergoing similar situations, of extended isolation. Would anyone have suggestions or advice? I am otherwise a healthy 26 year old male, exercise daily for a minimum of 45 minutes, and have regular interactions with friends where I live currently, etc.